# Clone variable in Word VBA

Tags: vba, object, ms-word, copy

Given the range with revisions in it, I need to reconstruct the original text and the modified text. The first solution was to:

```
Sub OriginalText (ByVal Rng as Range)
Rng.Revisions.RejectAll
OriginalText = Rng.Text
End sub
```

Yet it turned out that ByVal is not really ByVal. the moment RejectAll is called, all changes are rejected in original document as well, and there is no way to apply them - they're gone from ThisDocument.Revisions.

Is there a (preferably handy) way to copy the variable Rng to any (say,Rng2) in the sub so I can work with the copy of the range without affecting the source?

Is there a way to serialized the range and bring it together, maybe?

Upd: Let me put it this way. Is there a chance to copy the object (Range in my case) so the changes made to the copy won't affect the source? I think that still is the fastest and the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Range is a marker, even though it returns the content of the range. If you want the text, you need to say so.

```
Set r = Selection.Range
TextNow = Selection.Range.Text
TextOrig = OriginalText(r)
```

Comment: When the `.RejectAll` is called in the subroutine, it's clearing all the revisions (presumably the 0th "revision" as well, as there is no text left in that range)

Comment: The question was not on how to access the text string, but more on how to create the new range from existing one. Range keeps the revisions, which text obviously doesn't.

Comment: @user962409 You asked why ByVal range did not work, it does not work because you are sending a range, which is a marker or markers for a location, so you can change the range (ie start and end point) and ByVal will come into play, but if you change the text by Rejectall, you are changing the content of the range, ie the text, so ByVal is pointless.

Comment: @jonseca As far as I can see, the problem is a misunderstanding of what Range is. It seems to me that it is being seen as the content (text) of a range, rather than the range itself, which is just a start and end point.

Answer (score 0):

`.RejectAll` seems to be clearing all of the revisions (including when the text was first entered).  It would be convenient if we could access `.Revisions(0)`, but it doesn't look like this is possible.

Your best bet may be to see if you can store the original document before the changes are made.  If that is not possible, you could go through with something like [this script](http://www.thedoctools.com/downloads/basTrackChanges_Extract.shtml) and find all of the changes by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Range.Duplicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.duplicate.aspx), which seems to create a clone of the range.